# Lineary independent of subset in $C([a,b])$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Consider subset of $C([a,b])$, where $a<b$:

$\lbrace e^{ts}\rbrace_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$.

I need to show, that this subset is lineary independent. I know how to deal with it, when $s\in [a,\infty)$. Just take arbitrary distinct numbers $t_1, t_2,\ldots, t_N\in\mathbb{R}$, and assume, that for some $t_i$ (WLoG $i=1$) there exist $\alpha_i$ ($i=2,3,\ldots, N$), witch satisfies:

$e^{t_1s} = \sum_{j=2}^{N}\alpha_je^{t_js}$. Now I can multiply by $e^{-t_ks}$, where $t_k = \max\lbrace t_1, t_2,\ldots, t_N\rbrace$.

$e^{(t_1-t_k)s} = \sum_{j=2}^{N}\alpha_je^{(t_j-t_k)s}$.

EDIT: WLoG $\alpha_k\neq 0$.

Now taking $\lim_{s\to\infty}$ of both sides gives a contradiction. To see this just consider two cases: $k=1$, and $k\neq 1$.

How I tried to do it on $[a,b]$?...

Just take Vandermonde determinant $W(t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_N)$, because multiplying it by

$\prod_{i=1}^{N}e^{t_is}$ I will obtain determinant of a matrix $(a_{ij})$, where $a_{ij} = \frac{d^j}{dt^j}e^{t_is}$. But I don't know what is the next step, of course assuming, this is the right path to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose you have $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{N}a_j\exp(st_j)=0$ on $I=[a,b]$, with distincts $t_j$, then mutiplying by $\exp(-st_N)$ give $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{N-1}a_j\exp(s(t_j-t_N))+a_N=0$. Now, you can compute the derivative, and use an induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the linear subspace $C^\infty ([a,b])\subset C([a,b])$ of indefinitely differentiable functions and the linear operator of differentiation $$D:C^\infty ([a,b])\to C^\infty ([a,b]):f\mapsto f'$$ 
The function $e_t(x)=e^{tx}$ is an eigenvector for $D$ with eigenvalue $t$ since $D(e_t)=te_t$.
Since non-zero eigenvectors with different eigenvalues are linearly independent, the $e_t$'s are linearly independent in $C^\infty ([a,b])$ and thus also in $C([a,b])$.

Comment: Elegant this way really

Comment: Glad you like it, Maciej !